# What changes can i make in the config file to set the GPS config?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

For the recent google play store changes that will affect apps targeting API version 21 (Android 5.0, Lollipop) or higher that use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION but don't explicitly have the "android.hardware.location.gps" uses-feature.

Given is the solution for the native application:
                
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Sna.png
But the given solution is for Native application. I needed the solution for hybrid application as I am using Phonegap to build the Apps. What changes can i make in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

Try using custom config. Here's the link.

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config

Add the plugin, then copy and paste the code from your picture.

Then, it'll be something like,

```
<platform name="android">
  <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
  </config-file>
</platform>
```